# How to to configure other browsers to test on Vellamo

Tags: mobile, browser

For Vellamo Mobile Benchmark, the HTML5 Chapter evaluates mobile web browser performance.
When running the benchmark, does it test using the default browser?
If there are several browsers installed on the Android device, how are other browsers configured to test on Vellamo?

Answer (score 1):

The Vellamo HTML5 Chapter benchmarks the [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) component. It's the web engine used in the "Browser" APP as well as thousands of other APPS, which use it as layouting engine or to render online content.

Because of a limitation in the Android framework, Vellamo cannot test other Browsers. In Android 4.0 (I believe), the framework was adapted so that users could be able to switch to different web engines (for example Chrome), but afaik there is no simple way to activate this new behavior. I believe that in the future, Android will allow to select different web engines and if that happens Vellamo will probably offer the option to benchmark them.